# LINQ to Entities and many to many

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

**Edited to the latest issue/concern**

I'm using EF1 and trying to do the following but having problems with my many-to-many relationship.  I have the BuildExpression extension method working to get around .Contains() not being available in EF1.

PagingUsers & Groups have a many-to-many relationship.

Here's what I have so far that works.

```
// Find many groups
public IQueryable<Group> FindGroupsByGroupIDs(List<int> group_ids)
{
    return db.Groups.Where(LINQHelpers.BuildContainsExpression<Group, int>(g => g.Group_ID, group_ids));
}

// Find users in a group
public IQueryable<PagingUser> FindPagingUsersByGroupID(int group_id)
{
    return db.PagingUsers.Include("Groups").Where(u => u.Groups.Any(g => g.Group_ID == group_id));
}
```

Now I would like to combine these and find the users that are in a list of groups.

```
public IQueryable<PagingUser> FindPagingUsersByGroupIDs(List<int> group_ids)
{
    return from g in db.Groups.Where(LINQHelpers.BuildContainsExpression<Group,int>(g => g.Group_ID, group_ids))
            join p in db.PagingUsers on ???
            select p;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query works as-is in .NET 4.0. For .NET 3.5, search for "BuildContainsExpression".

Comment: Resolved my types cannot be inferred problem, but my many to many relationship complicates the expression

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public IQueryable<PagingUser> FindPagingUsersByGroupIDs(List<int> group_ids)
{
    var gids = group_ids.ToArray();
    return from p in db.PagingUsers
            where p.Groups.Any(g => gids.Contains(g.Group_ID))
            select p;
}
```

As for the second question: which lambda do you want to get rid of? The inner or the outer? And why?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @ryan  It should for an array though.

Comment: Not for EF1. Has problems with all IEnumerable as far as I know

Comment: @ryan - I just tried it with EF1 and it worked fine for me. I know that `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't work, but I haven't had problems using arrays of primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your second question :

I don't understand why you are converting it into an Upper case bound. For your kind information, Linq query is not case sensitive if you want it to be iterated in a case sensitive manner it should be done iterating the list or the first item as it depends, which you got by executing the  LINQ and then do it  pro-grammatically and search the cases.